# How to get words by a given pattern of a variable in shell (Jenkinsfile)?

Tags: shell, jenkins, sed, grep, jenkins-pipeline

Currently I am facing a problem of how to extract the name of some test classes from a variable (Shell) in my Jenkinsfile.

Scenario: Every time a Pull request is created in Bitbucket, a Pipeline type job is activated in Jenkins where I have access to the variable called "description" in the Jenkinsfile.

For example, the input of the description variable can contain the following:

---

### US-2371
Any description here
Test Classes: testclass1_tst,testclass_test
Any other description here.

Expected output:
Save in another variable only the following:
testclass1_tst,testclass_test

Note: I need the names of the test classes separated by ',' and the pattern is those test classes that end in tst, test, Test.

Thanks in advance.

Reference:

[Jenkinsfile - Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKLEU.png)

Comment: It is easier to read the extract from your jenkinsfile if you post it as text and not a image. If you do, please use markup.

Comment: Is the keyword "Test Classes" always going to be there?

Comment: @Ruchi Hi, yes (Test Classes:) always going be there just the filenames of the test classes will change always

Answer (score 0):

Since **Test Classes:** is going to be present in all the descriptions, we can look for it and parse out classes.

`echo $description | sed -r 's/(.*Test Classes: )(\w.+)([[:space:]])(.*)/\2/`

This would get you
`testclass1_tst,testclass_test`

Comment: Hi Ruchi I have an error in the test from Jenkins.

From Jenkins: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 128: expecting '}', found 's' @ line 128, column 57.
    'echo $description | sed -r 's/(.*Test 
                                 ^
From Jenkinsfile:
sh 'echo $description | sed -r 's/(.*Test Classes: )(\w.+)([[:space:]])(.*)/\2/''

Note: It doesn't work between double quotes either
(sh "echo $description | sed -r 's/(.*Test Classes: )(\w.+)([[:space:]])(.*)/\2/'")

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps try testing the command in a shell before pasting in the file?